# Prism 7 Singleton with two Interfaces

Tags: c#, prism

I'm looking at the container abstractions introduced in Prism 7 and I'm unsure about how to register one singleton with two interfaces.

Coming from a unity background, I register the singleton first (without interface) and then both of the interfaces (not as singleton):

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<FactoryController>();
containerRegistry.Register<IFactoryController, FactoryController>();
containerRegistry.Register<IFactoryToken, FactoryController>();
```

This works fine, as my container is unity. But will it work with other containers, too?

Are there any specifications available for the behaviour of the container abstractions provided by Prism 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prism 7 Container abstractions are purposely simple and intended to handle MOST but NOT ALL of your registration needs. For more complex scenarios you will need to get the container using the extension method `GetContainer()` as shown here:

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<FactoryController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<IFactoryController>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<FactoryController>()));
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<IFactoryToken>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<FactoryController>()));
```

Comment: I suspected something like that. A pity this abstraction is visible to the user at all. While I understand the benefit for the library that has to support different containers, it makes things complex for the application even though that one only wants to use its container.

Comment: The reality is that the abstraction layer benefits the majority of developers. The sad reality is that most developers never bother to learn or understand much if anything at all about Dependency Injection or the containers they are using. The result is that the Prism team is left trying to support developers problems that are container specific. This lowers the bar of entry making a consistent API across containers for 95%+ of what you need to register which also opens the door to writing a Module that could be used across apps even when those apps use different DI Containers.

Comment: Now if you feel that there is a specific API such as this that needs to be added you are welcome to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @DanS. Prism version 7.1.0.431 throws a StackOverflow exception if I try to use this code.

Comment: @Jinjinov the only thing that could potentially throw a StackOverflowException would be Unity not Prism, and I've used that with Prism 7.1/Unity so there has to be something in your code that's causing the issue.

Comment: @DanS. thank you, I have resolved this by separating the two interfaces.